# Data transmission Serial to TCP

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, tcpip

I am trying to send numeric data using ESP8266 to local network python server. Before that I am collecting data from sensors using Arduino UNO and then send it to ESP using hardware serial.

ESP8266 code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "ssid";
const char* password = "pass";

const char* host = "192.168.1.103";

String serial_data;

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

   delay(5000);

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections

  const int port = 8888;
  if (!client.connect(host, port)) 
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

}

void loop() {

  delay(200);

  while(Serial.available() <= 0)
  {
    //wait for arduino serial data
  }

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    // This will send data to client via TCP
    Serial.println("Sent..");
    serial_data = String(Serial.read());
    client.print(serial_data);
  }
}
```

Python Server code:

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase("data.db")

class post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField()
    current = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

#connecting to database
def initialize_db():
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([post], safe = True)

initialize_db()

HOST = '192.168.1.103'  
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#keep talking with the client
#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print data

        #send data to database
        post.create(
            current = data
        )

        reply = 'OK ->' + data
        if not data:
            break

        conn.sendall(reply)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

After powering up ESP it successfully connects to server and then simulating arduino esp serial communication I am using serial monitor to send some numbers. Before I send anything server outputs number 240:

```
Connected with 192.168.1.100:26137
240
```

Then I am sending number 1 but on server terminal I get numbers 49 and 13. Sending numbers some 2 - 3 times and no more data are outputted to server terminal. Should I parse data received from serial to some form I can transmit it via TCP or data should be processed on server side?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are ASCII Codes (here is [a chart](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ASCIIchart) from the Arduino website). 49 is the number 1, and 13 is a carriage return ('\n'). There should be a setting in the bottom right corner of Serial Monitor to change line ending, this should be set to "no line ending." If it is, than `client.print()` must be adding the carriage return, so you will need to remove it in Python. If you are only sending integers, replace

```
serial_data = String(Serial.read());
```

with:

```
serial_data = String(Serial.parseInt());
```

In the Python code I suggest adding a print statement to check if the connection is closed after

```
#came out of loop
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you also explain why after sending number 1 to server it prints 3 times these values 49 and 13 but after I can send anything and server receives nothing?

Comment: Is the connection being closed, or is it just not receiving anything?